# Swift using Objective-C class

Tags: swift, gcdasyncsocket

I am trying to use GCDAsyncSocket to connect my app.

I get compilation errors. When I try this:

```
    class Connection : NSObject {    
    var connected: Bool
    var tcpSocket: GCDAsyncSocket?
    var myHost: String = "127.0.0.1"
    var myPort: UInt16 = 0

    init() {
        connected = false
    }
    func initialize(host: String, port: UInt16) {

    }
    func connect() {
        tcpSocket = GCDAsyncSocket(delegate: self, delegateQueue: dispatch_get_main_queue())
        var error: NSError?
        tcpSocket!.connectToHost(myHost, port: myPort, error: error)

    }
}
```

I get: 
"Missing argument for parameter 'withTimeout' in call"
when changing to this:

```
class Connection : NSObject {    
var connected: Bool
var tcpSocket: GCDAsyncSocket?
var myHost: String = "127.0.0.1"
var myPort: UInt16 = 0

init() {
    connected = false
}
func initialize(host: String, port: UInt16) {

}
func connect() {
    tcpSocket = GCDAsyncSocket(delegate: self, delegateQueue: dispatch_get_main_queue())
    var connectionError: NSError?
    tcpSocket!.connectToHost(myHost, port: myPort, withTimeout: -1.0, error: connectionError)

}}
```

I get: 
"Extra argument 'withTimeout' in call"
I am confused...

Comment: Seems like it was the error pointer that was causing the error. changed it to &connectionError and the errors went away.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The definition of that method is:

```
- (BOOL)connectToHost:(NSString *)host onPort:(uint16_t)port error:(NSError **)errPtr;
```

A closer look at the last parameter `errPtr` reveals that you have to pass the pointer to a variable of type `NSError`. That translates in swift as a parameter passed using the `inout` modifier.

So the correct way to call that method is:

```
tcpSocket!.connectToHost(myHost, onPort: myPort, error: &error)
```

*Note* that there was a mispelled parameter in your code: `port: myPort` should be `onPort: myPort`

Comment: the onPort part I figured out, I did a copy paste error. Eventually I did get it to work but thanks a lot for the reply.